# Eclipse 2019-09, can't see the current column number in the status bar

Tags: eclipse

I've noticed the following on Eclipse 2019-09 R (4.13.0) for macOS, but it might have happened before: I can't see the current line columns anymore on the status bar:

[image: Eclipse status bar]

for the obvious reason that the box is too small and the abbreviation is triggered. But I can't find a way to extend it, I've already tried to click and drag with no luck. This is very annoying when I need it.

Is there some option to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Eclipse bug [551387](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551387) which is marked as fixed in Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14)

A workaround is to turn off 'Show cursor position in the status line' in the 'General > Editors > Text Editors' page of the Preferences.

Comment: I've tried "Show cursor position in the status line" and everything disappeared, even the line number :-( I'll update to 2019-12.

Comment: Oh, no! The status bar is fine now, but completely different when I compare with egit, thank you!

Comment: I am running 2019-12 (4.14).  If I am editing Java, the cursor position is displayed.  If I am editing XML, the cursor position is NOT displayed.  If XML is handled by a Structured Text Editor, then 'General > Editors > Structured Text Editors' does not have 'Show cursor position in the status line.'  How can someone edit XML and see what column they're in?